# PHP check two dates in one week for contdown

Tags: php, date

I have two events on two days each week. Both starting on 13:15 at each day. Each tuesday and each thursday. I need to check if the nearest event (from now()) is tuesday (till 13:15) OR thursday (till 13:15) to set the javascript countdown correctly (it will get the date("Y-m-d H:i:s") string for counting)

PSEUDO EXAMPLE:

```
if( tuesday("13:15") == 'over' &&  thursday("13:15") == 'remaining' ) {
  echo 'Next event start thursday 13:15'; 
  // need time format here for the thursday
} else {
  echo 'Next event start tuesday 13:15'; 
  // need time format here for the tuesday
}
```

I'm struggling with comparing the time ranges:

```
$now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));

$event_time = '13:15';
$event_tuesday = new DateTime("next tuesday");
$event_thursday = new DateTime("next thursday");

echo $diff_tuesday = $event_tuesday->diff($now)->format("%a");
echo $diff_thursday = $event_thursday->diff($now)->format("%a");
```

But i think that's anyway wrong.
Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the power of PHP's [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) which understands strings like `next Tuesday`, `next month + 1 day`, etc.

Please see comments in the following code snippet.

Please also note that you must [set the default timezone as appropriate.](http://php.net/manual/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

```
// Current instant:
$now = time();

// 13:15 of today's day if it's Tuesday (regardless of the current time), 
// otherwise the next upcoming Tuesday:
$thisTuesday1315 = strtotime("this Tuesday 13:15");

// 13:15 of today's day if it's Thursday (regardless of the current time), 
// otherwise the next upcoming Thursday:
$thisThursday1315 = strtotime("this Thursday 13:15");

if($thisTuesday1315 <= $now || ($now < $thisThursday1315 && $thisThursday1315 < $thisTuesday1315)) {
    echo 'Next event start: Thursday 13:15';
    // You may use the `$thisThursday1315` timestamp here
} else {
    echo 'Next event start: Tuesday 13:15';
    // You may use the `$thisTuesday1315` timestamp here
}
```

Comment: ok in germany now we got thuesday 21:18. if i try your code with live date: strtotime("next Tuesday 22:00") > strtotime("next Thursday 22:00") it should give me this thursday as answer. but gives me next tuesday! ..problem is the "next" string...cos we got thursday and no need for next here. you understand my problem?

Comment: @trajo, now I understand the problem; 
after playing around with `strtotime` I figured out that `this Tuesday <TIME>` returns the today's instant with the specified time if today is Tuesday (regardless of the current time), otherwise it returns the upcoming Tuesday. I have updated the code snippet accordingly.

Comment: working as expected and i marked it as correct answer! Thx Alex ...@other please also see  Ali's solution. A great set of functions for dynmaically more events. But for my need i will use Alex one and save Ali's one ;)

Answer (score 0):

We needed to include the current time into the equation.

Also based on the event's time we have to workout if the its *this* or *next* given day, this will take place within the `prependThisOrNext()` method

In the following solution, you wont be limited to only two events a week.

```
<?php

function prependThisOrNext($dayAndTime)
{
    $prefix = strtotime($dayAndTime) > strtotime('now') ? 'this ' : 'next ';
    return $prefix . $dayAndTime;
}

function sortEvents($events = [])
{
    $list = [];
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $prependedEvent = prependThisOrNext($event);
        $list[strtotime($prependedEvent)] = $prependedEvent;
    }

    asort($list);
    return $list;
}

function getTheNextEvent($events = [])
{
    $sortedList = sortEvents($events);
    return array_shift($sortedList);
}

$events = ['Tuesday 13:15', 'Thursday 22:15'];

$nextEvent = getTheNextEvent($events);

echo 'Next event: ' . $nextEvent;
```

Please keep in mind working with such array of free strings as argument will require some good validation/safeguarding :)

Comment: A Great solutions, THX! I marked Alex one as answer cos he focused on only the logic part and was quicker but you gave a great example for dynamical use. I def will need it in other place. I marked it as useful!